# Unable to use freeze_graph.py with tf.contrib.image.rotate() in TF 1.0.1

Tags: tensorflow

I currently use `tf.contrib.image.rotate()` to augment my training data. When I try to freeze the corresponding graph I receive the following error:

> ValueError: No op named ImageProjectiveTransform in defined operations.

When I remove `tf.contrib.image.rotate()` from the graph, `freeze_graph.py` finishes normally.

Why does this error occur? What is the easiest work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because `freeze_graph.py` doesn't have access to the contrib ops (like the one you're using). I think you need to file a github issue to get a permanent fix, but a temporary fix is to add an import of `tensorflow.contrib.image` to `freeze_graph.py` and rerun.

Comment: Your work-around works. Thanks! The question I have now though is why I don't need to use the same work-around for `tf.contrib.slim` which I also use in my graph?

Comment: slim doesn't add any new op kernels, just a nicer UI to use them

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 10 with tensorflow installed via pip. Any other ideas?

Comment: probably a bug in freeze_graph that needs to be fixed.  It doesn't know how to freeze native ops?  BlockLSTM is also an issue.