# Tensorflow Eigen/Freeze_graph issue

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I've got a trained model that I want to put on my iPhone for inference. I've used Tensorflow, and obtained the necessary `graph.pb` and a checkpoint file. I use the `freeze_graph.py` script to freeze the graph with weights but I get the error:
`google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : Expected identifier or number.` On the line where the script tries to read in the graph.

I tried using the method which is mentioned [here](http://machinethink.net/blog/tensorflow-on-ios/) and installed bazel. However when I do a `bazel build tensorflow/python:freeze_graph`, it gives me the error that Eigen was not found in the deps. This is right since the Eigen is in another folder.

I understand there's two things I'm asking here:

- How to freeze a graph properly given my error.
- If bazel is required for using `freeze_graph` how to get around the Eigen dependency.

I've also referenced [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3743) issue as well, but it didn't help since I'm using a Mac and configured tensorflow to build without CUDA support.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue with one of the tf.contrib ops. The work-around solution was to add an import statement in `freeze_graph` to import that module as described in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43331705/5587428)

Comment: I see, however do you know what module to add? Eigen supposedly is in two locations in the repo

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know. From what I've read eigen is used extensively for core ops, so perhaps you're experiencing a different issue.

Comment: Alright I'll try to figure it out